# Parsing a static JSON file into a Rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, flickr

I'm trying to parse a static JSON file from my root directory into an already predefined object, but I'm getting confused on how to get the object to "read" each attribute within the JSON file and display it as its own. I hope I'm not making this more confusing from what it is?

Some of my code:

```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_post, except: [:index, :show]

  # @@posts = File.read('app/assets/javascripts/flickr_feed.json')
  # @posts = JSON.parse(string)

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @@posts }
      # format.json { render json: @@posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /post/1
  # GET /post/1.json
  def show
    @post = @post.assign_attributes JSON.parse(File.read('app/assets/javascripts/flickr_feed.json'))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
  ...
```

If I go to `localhost:3000/posts.json` I see the desire output..

```
{
"title": "Recent Uploads tagged potato",
"link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/potato/",
"description": "",
"modified": "2015-11-21T08:41:44Z",
"generator": "https://www.flickr.com/",
"posts": [ // before was "items":
 {
  "title": "Hokkaido potato with butter",
  "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/taking5/22873428920/",
  "media": {"m":"https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5813/22873428920_3cac20cc47_m.jpg"},
  "date_taken": "2015-07-18T08:16:24-08:00",
  "description": " <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/taking5/\">Taking5<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/taking5/22873428920/\" title=\"Hokkaido potato with butter\"><img src=\"https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5813/22873428920_3cac20cc47_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"180\" alt=\"Hokkaido potato with butter\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>Yummy.<\/p>",
  "published": "2015-11-21T08:41:44Z",
  "author": "nobody@flickr.com (Taking5)",
  "author_id": "58375502@N00",
  "tags": "japan hokkaido potato hakodate morningmarket"
 }
]
}
 ...
```

But if I go to the `posts#index` I don't see anything. I know I'm not parsing the data properly, but I'm getting confused on how to do that.

**Summary:** I would like to parse each **item** from JSON file so as to be able to do `post.title`, `post.description`, etc.

**Edit:** Update on code in the controller.

Comment: Hint: when you do `format.html` it is expecting a block of code (some code between curly braces, like you have for `format.json`)

Comment: @Sunil D, tried what you recommended ```format.html{ render @posts }```, but now it says that I'm missing a partial and when I do create the partial ```<%= render partial: @posts  -%>``` I get an ```stack too deep error```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
@post = Post.new
@post.assign_attributes JSON.parse(File.read('app/assets/javascripts/flickr_feed.json'))
```

If you use `protected_attributes` gem, attributes set using this manner must be defined with `attr_accessible` in the model or parameter `without_protection` must be used.

Edit:

```
def index
  @posts =
    JSON.parse(File.read('app/assets/javascripts/flickr_feed.json'))["posts"].inject([]) do |_posts, post_attrs|
      _posts << Post.new(post_attrs)
    end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Comment: @Mereq, I thought attr_accessible was deprecated in Rails 4??  And the gem ```protected_parameters``` seem to be failling.

Comment: In Rails 4 strong parameters are introduced and `protected_attributes` has been moved to a gem. If you don't use it, you can of course skip that notice.

Comment: I supplemented my answer.

Comment: thanks man. Is there any way I could do it without the said gem? If not of course the I'll use the gem. But was trying to solve it first without any gems... Thanks for taking the time answering man.

Comment: so wait I'm still unable to display the data.  I can see it if I go to ```posts.json``` but when I go to ```post/1.json``` I get the following error : ```776: unexpected token at 'jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged potato",
    "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/potato/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2015-11-21T08:41:44Z",
    "generator": "https://www.flickr.com/",
    "posts": [
     {...```
I updated my code a bit.

Comment: That occurs because this is not a valid JSON file. Remove the `jsonFlickrFeed(` and the closing bracket and try again.

Comment: still nothing. What am I missing? AAARGGGHH!!. About to destroy my computer. - _ -

Comment: After your edit I see, that posts should be created from `"posts"` key of given hash extracted from JSON file. More appropriate is to use `index` action to output it. I've edited my answer. This is not a nice solution to do what you mean but some good start to future refactoring.

Comment: thanks man it's actually working now. What do you think would be the best way to parse and utilize an external api into rails. I'm suppose to use an angular to create an app that consumes that api.

Comment: I think this is good approach for high loaded apps, if you're going to leverage some load from server to the client.